# File Output node name

Tags: export

Is it possible to use wildcards when exporting with the File Output Node? I use a DAW called Reaper that have that feature -to export with all possible variations.

So what I'd like to be able to write in the  (dollarSign)sceneName(dollarSign)dateTime.png... ah, you get it.

So it dosen't overwrite the same Image001 over and over again and so I can keep all renders. Is this possible? Some Addon?

Or is it possible to modify the current File Output Node? What would be even better perhaps?